# how to call a java function from javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I've seen many tutorials, but none of them have worked in my case, I think it is because I'm using a .jar instead of an .class and in that .jar, I have more than just one Java class.
Anyone knows how to solve this?

code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1430071/code.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the DWR answers, they misunderstood your architecture. Applet code runs on client, not server.

What error message do you get?

Is the method you are trying to call public?

The way you are calling the Java method, the method has to be in the applet class. Is it?

It seems like your applet tag is missing the code attribute. It's required. Quoting an example from Oracle:

```
  <applet codebase="http://java.sun.com/applets/NervousText/1.1"
    code="NervousText.class" width=400 height=75>
  <param name="text" value="Welcome to HotJava!">
  <hr>
  If you were using a Java-enabled browser such as HotJava,
  you would see dancing text instead of this paragraph.
  <hr>
  </applet>
```

The code attribute must reference an applet class (a class that extends java.awt.Applet or javax.swing.JApplet) that can be found in one of the jars you've listed in the archive attribute. This has to be the full name of the class, something like: my.package.MyApplet (the .class at the end is optional).

Comment: Don't get any error, just no action at all.
Yes it's public.
It is in one of the classes contained in the jar.
It does, I use the default package to work so no path before the class is required and yes Rama it's a an applet. 
Everything seems ok :/

Comment: My bad, I somehow didn't see the code attribute, but it's there. Does your applet get executed? Does it do something before you call (or try calling) the method? If you try to call another method, for example, the toString() method, does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to call server side java from client side javascript?  You would need to wire up a DWR call.

Comment: When dealing with applets, doesn't the classes run on the client? So there wouldn't be a server side code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood that you were using an applet.  It can be done, but it isn't pretty, you can use the "javascript:" protocol to trigger a function on the page.  For example:  getAppletContext().showDocument
        (new URL("javascript:doAlert('Hi JavaScript World!')"));

Answer (score 0):

As Joe mentioned, DWR can help you here. Here a [link](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/examples/index.html) to their tutorials.